# Django Ldap Authentication using default function

Tags: django, python-2.7, authentication, ldap

I am new to django . I am trying to authenticate my django against the LDAP server . I saw the django-ldap documentation regarding the settings and i configured my settings accordingly :

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap.forumsys.com"

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "password"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com",
    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")
```

My doubt is
1) what would i have in my Views .
2) should i hav to redirect my url to my views again ?
3) how would i run this ?

Thank you

Comment: You need to install django-ldap module in any case. It is implemented over python-ldap functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have included 'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend' in AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS in your settings.py and other relevant configurations. You just have authenticate the user using  
user = authenticate(username=user_name, password=password) in you view where user_name and password are form you use for login page.
     try:
        
    user = authenticate(username=userName, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                        if user.is_active:
                                   auth.login(request, user)
                                   return HttpResponseRedirect('')
                      else:
                               pass 
    except LDAPError as e:
                  pass

Comment: Thanks for the help . Is the username and password are as same as the bind_dn and bind_password which we have mentioned in the settings.py .

Since i am using an open ldap server , i donot have an username for it

Comment: no username and password are to validate against each user's username and password like we usually have in auth_user, bind_dn and bind_password are your password to access your LDAP

Comment: Sorry i am not able to get you . Can you be more clear pls :

Comment: those user name and password are the one you receive from your login form